# How to pass choice display name to model serialize in Django REST framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My env is Django 2.0.3, DRF 3.8.2 and Python 3.6.4.

I have a model in `serializers.py`:

```
class TransferCostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        field_view = super().to_representation(instance)
        if field_view['is_active']:
            return field_view
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = TransferCost
        fields = ('id', 'destination', 'total_cost', 'is_active',)
```

Where `destination` field is choice field of 3 elements:

```
DESTINATION = (
    ('none', _('I will drive by myself')),
    ('transfer_airport', _('Only from airport')),
    ('transfer_round_trip', _('Round trip')),
)
```

This is my `models.py`:

```
class TransferCost(models.Model):

    destination = models.CharField(
        _('Transfer Destination'), choices=DESTINATION, max_length=55
    )
    total_cost = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        _('Total cost'), default=0
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('Transfer active?'), default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Transfer')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Transfers')

    def __str__(self):
        return _('Transfer {}').format(self.destination)
```

..And I return JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        destination: "transfer_airport",
        total_cost: 25,
        is_active: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        destination: "transfer_round_trip",
        total_cost: 45,
        is_active: true
    }
]
```

How to return `destination` field with his display name? For example:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        destination_display: "Only from airport",
        destination: "transfer_round_trip",
        total_cost: 25,
        is_active: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        destination_display: "Round trip",
        destination: "transfer_round_trip",
        total_cost: 45,
        is_active: true
    }
]
```

Would be great to have something like `get_FOO_display()` in `serializers.py`, but it's not working. I need this thing, because I render form dynamically via Vue.js (as `v-for` select list).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can use [fields source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) with [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

```
class TransferCostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    destination_display = serializers.CharField(
        source='get_destination_display'
    )
```

Comment: if I'm not mistake it is default for the functions

Comment: As I'm writing today (with Django: 3.1.6) this seemed non-default.

Answer (score 3):

just place `get_destination_display` withoput `()` in `fields`. like this:

```
class TransferCostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TransferCost
        fields = ('id', 'get_destination_display', 'total_cost', 'is_active',)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have the values of all model fields with choices to be returned as display values, following worked out for me:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist

class TransferCostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TransferCost
        fields = ('id', 'destination', 'total_cost', 'is_active',)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """
        Overwrites choices fields to return their display value instead of their value.
        """
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        for field in data:
            try:
                if instance._meta.get_field(field).choices:        
                    data[field] = getattr(instance, "get_" + field + "_display")()
            except FieldDoesNotExist:
                pass
        return data
```

The other solutions dropped auto generated meta-information of the model fields, e.g., translated labels.